# How to lazy load my article card using Intersection Observer?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, lazy-loading, intersection-observer

I have an HTML page where I arranged 6 cards using a CSS grid. I want them to ***lazy load t***hose cards using **Intersection Observer**. At a first glance, people will see only two or three cards in a row according to the viewport width, after scrolling down people will see a total of 6 cards. Suppose I have 40 cards. What if I want to load only 6 cards at first and the rest of the card only when the user scrolls. I tried to implement this but failed. Can anyone help me to achieve this?  Here is my [GitHub repository link](https://github.com/shahab570/lazy-Load)

Comment: I have created this plugin that uses the intersection observer api - https://github.com/maxshuty/simply-lazy take a look at my `SimplyLazy.js` file and it should help you out

Comment: is this plugin only for images?

Comment: Anything that uses the `src` tag, but you might be able to extract some logic from it